# Reading user input without echoing

Tags: r

I'm wondering if there is a way that I can read user input from STDIN without echoing it back to the screen in R. I know that `readline()`, `readLines()` and `scan()` can read in user input from the keyboard but none appear to have an option to not echo back.

As you might expect this is to grab a password. So I'm looking for something that would let me do:

```
> a<-get_password()
Password:
> a
[1] "password"
```

Comment: Can't be done cross-platformly easily, usual solution is tcltk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917202 - but if you really need it from STDIN...

Comment: possible duplicate of [R: Way to securely give a password to R application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917202/r-way-to-securely-give-a-password-to-r-application)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's the operating system? If you can run it from a terminal, this should work.

```
get_password <- function() {
cat("Password: ")
system("stty -echo")
a <- readline()
system("stty echo")
cat("\n")
return(a)
}

> a <- get_password()
Password: 
> a
[1] "sdfs"
>
```

This works on OS X using R from Terminal.app, but not from R.app. No idea on a Windows solution, since there doesn't seem to be a native R solution.

Comment: This is great, at the moment I'm only dealing with Mac/Linux so this will serve perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: This works on Linux (tested on Ubuntu) as well, as expected given that it's a UNIX-based trick.

Answer (score 5):

If this is for a more production-style environment, then you might consider using [R-Tcl/Tk](http://www.ci.tuwien.ac.at/Conferences/DSC-2001/Proceedings/Dalgaard.pdf), which has a "Show" parameter for password entry.