# How to hide elements in R environment?

Tags: r, passwords

I work with an SQL database connecting to it in RStudio, and I am trying to find a way to hide my password from other colleagues for common reasons. I cam across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13034402/14984365) using `.rs.askForPassword`. However, the created element still shows up in environment in the values area showcasing the password entered on the screen. Is there a way to create it as a hidden object? Or, perhaps, an alternative solution for handling DB passwords altogether?

Comment: perhaps `keyring` is an option? https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000969634-Using-Keyring-in-the-RStudio-IDE

Comment: See also the `{keychain}` package.

Comment: @Wimpel it suits me perfectly and is a quick fix, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to  a suggestion by @Wimpel I used Keyring to fix my problem. A little more detailed look into it can be seen [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000969634-Using-Keyring-in-the-RStudio-IDE). In short, I used the command `rstudioapi::askForSecret` directly in SQL server connection setup, so I don't have to create an object containing my password `dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), password = **rstudioapi::askForSecret("password")**)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you work with sql, have you tried to just simply hash it with SHA1 encryption ?

```
SHA1(string)
```

You can also tick an option to hide the values in phpmyadmin thus showcasing it with `***`

Comment: But I still need to see other elements' values. Anyways, ```rstudioapi::askForSecret``` solved the problem.