# How can I get the siteId of the current site with Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, spfx

From the documentation, I can't find any ways to get the siteId of the site where I put the webpart in.

For example,

My current site is: `https://{hostname}/sites/main1` <-- NOT root site, but I want to get this siteId

and I test my webpart here: `https://{hostname}/sites/main1/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx`

How can I achieve this? From the documentation,

> A site is addressed be a unique identifier which is a composite ID of the following values:
>
> > Site collection hostname (contoso.sharepoint.com)
> >
> > Site collection unique ID (guid)
> >
> > Site unique ID (guid)

I can get the hostname easily by using `location.hostname` (Yes, I am using JavaScript + React to build my webpart) but how to get the site-id easily with Graph API?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try this: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{hostname}:/sites/{path}?$select=id`
For example:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/cie493742.sharepoint.com:/sites/Contoso/Operations/Manufacturing?$select=id` (this one you can try on the Graph Explorer.

What you get back in the id is in this format:

```
{hostname},{spsite.id},{spweb.id}
```

For more info here is the link to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Culmination of 3 hours of searching. [This](https://support.cloudhq.net/how-to-find-guids-of-sharepoint-sites/) was partially useful but only provides the site-id

Comment: There is always something kind of OFF with Microsoft documentation. They are usually vague or detailed to the point where they cannot be understood.

Comment: I hate Microsoft specifically for documentation

Comment: What if path contains spaces, say, instead of Operations in the above example we have 'Operations ternary'? So the url turns out to be "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/cie493742.sharepoint.com:/sites/Contoso/Operations ternary/Manufacturing?$select=id", which doesn't work!! @WouldBeNerd

Comment: @KhushbooMulani in a url spaces are usually represented by %20 but I can't be sure that that would fix it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Execute the below query in Graph explorer

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{tenantname}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{sitename}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Btenantname%7D.sharepoint.com:/sites/%7Bsitename%7D)

replace the tenantname and sitename placeholders.

The key 'Id' in the JSON response holds the site Id value

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do a Graph API call to get the siteId of the current site. It is available in the [PageContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-page-context/pagecontext).

In the main class of your webpart you can find it at:

```
this.context.pageContext.site.id
```

Answer (score 2):

On classic sites using `spPageContextInfo`:

```
(location.host + "," + _spPageContextInfo.siteId + "," + _spPageContextInfo.webId).replace(/[\{\}]/g, "")
```

Comment: This works on Modern Sites too. Note that you only get the right site id if you've navigated to the Site Collection in question (or one of its Site Pages)

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can get the Site-id by below Graph Http Get API.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites

Comment: Awesome! Worked for me.

Comment: I don't think this always works, it's like the returned list doesn't include all of the sites, at least not in our SharePoint.