# Get password from R console

Tags: r

I wonder if it is possible to get password from R command line. I have tried several variants of the following, but characters are echoed on the screen when entered.

```
password = scan(file = "", what = character(), nmax = 1)
```

Comment: The lack of this ability without resorting to a separate UI component is one of the things that really annoys me with R

Comment: Just found a working solution for me. .rs.askForPassword("foo")

Comment: That solution isn't portable though.  Which is annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a UI component that knows a password is typed, and hence shows the stars.

The only portable one is part of the tcltk package, and has been recommended a few times in the past.

*Edit:* The [getPass](https://cran.r-project.org/package=getPass) package provides a wrapper to several underlying approaches.

Comment: Relevant question with the tcltk package versions that works in GUI environments, but not on the command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917202/way-to-securely-give-a-password-to-r-application

Comment: Just found a working solution for me provided by RStudio .rs.askForPassword("foo"). It does not have much documentation though.

Comment: Was just browsing for this and on an [RStudio support webpage](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000470088-function-rs-askForPassword-and-R-Markdown) `rstudioapi::askForPassword("")` is mentioned as a preferred function when using RStudio, also `getPass::getPass()` function  is mentioned there which seems to be a more versatile solution.