# Ask user crendentials when running R in Terminal

Tags: r, terminal, credentials, password-protection

I am running an `R script` from `Terminal` (not RStudio) and at some point I need the user to write the username and password to access an API. For this, I am using a non-safe approach with the following code:

```
cat('Write username: ')
username<-readLines("stdin", n=1)
cat('Write password: ')
password<-readLines("stdin", n=1)
```

I have seen there is a nice implementation in RStudio using the `rstudioapi` package and the `askForPassword` function but since I am running my script from Termianl, I wonder if there is any alternative or more secure way to ask for this information

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917202/way-to-securely-give-a-password-to-r-application-from-the-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getPass](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/getPass/index.html) is your best solution.

It supports RStudio and fallsback to tcltk and other backends if missing.

`password <- getPass::getPass()` is your call.